# Raising socket events from from nodejs code

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp

I am using net library in node. I want to raise a close event from my code. Is there any way i can do that?

If socket object is stored, I can perform `sock.destroy()` on it but the client will not be informed about the closing connection, which results in half dropped connection.

Is there any other way to handle this case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emit to that specific socket (client) a custom `'kill_connection'` event in order to inform the client about the connection being terminated for whatever reason you decided.

For example using `socket.io` :

```
var csid = socket.id; //The socket you are going to destroy
io.to(csid).emit('kill_connection');
```

Do this before performing the destruction of the socket.

Your client (if a webapp) could look something like:

```
socket.on("kill_connection", killSession);
    function killSession(){
       socket.disconnect();
       console.log("socket.disconnect");
       location.reload();
    }
```

The reload is in case you want a single-page webapp to show the login screen.

Comment: @user3508612 can't you extrapolate the example? Emit to that specific socket (a custom event for you to define in the client as a session close) before closing it server-side